# Material UI 5 - Circular Progress with Label, how to animate on load in?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-animations

I currently have the following progress circle from material UI[image]

The code I have is the following:

```
function CircularProgressWithLabel(props) {
return (
    <Box sx={{ position: 'relative', display: 'inline-flex' }}>
        <CircularProgress className="top-circle" variant="determinate" {...props}/>
        <CircularProgress className="bottom-circle" variant="determinate" value={100} />
    <Box
        sx={{
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: "130px",
        width: "130px"
        }}
    >
        <Typography variant="caption" component="div" color="text.secondary" style={{ fontSize: "24px" }}>
            {`${Math.round(props.value)}%`}
        </Typography>
    </Box>
    </Box>
);
}
```

How would I go about making this animated when loading the page? i.e. making the loading circle start from 0 and go to the required value instead of just starting like that? Also, having the number in the center keep up with the same progress bar when loading up

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could slowly increase that count until it reaches the expected count using useEffect()